# Extract rows containing non-numeric value in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a log file containing an average of *250,000* data.

I would like to filter the data such that if the message *(msg:)* in each row contains non-numeric data, I would like to extract the entire row of data and save it into a separate file. [Original sample file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Pnz5K7hj_YczIZzEZnzPyGQjZxpseca8)

E.g. The highlighted text in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts1bN.png) are the ones I would like to extract and save in a separate file.

However, I'm only able to remove the entire row of data, but not extracting the data and saving in a separate file. Following is the code I used to remove non-numeric values.

```
mydataset['timestamp'] = pd.to_numeric(mydataset['timestamp'], errors = 'ignore')
```

Comment: As I do not see any tabular format in your data, is there any reason why you are using `pandas` here?

Comment: @DarrenChristopher I churned out the data from another file using `panda`. Thus I continued using `panda`.